# Enter and tab are not going in req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I want that enter and tab should also go in the body of the request so that I can display the same thing (which I am typing in the textarea) when I render it back after saving it in mongoDB database.

Comment: where/how do you want to display it? Have you tried  `whitespace: "pre-wrap"`?

Comment: `<textarea class="inputText" name="content" placeholder="type here" required></textarea>`   Suppose this is the code and I am storing it in db. but the problem is that when I give multiple spaces, tab or enter then those exact structures of lines are not rendered from the db. The texts are separated by just one single space even if I provide tab or enter or multiple spaces.